# Is filesystemwatcher detectable?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, logfile

i wanna ask you if is filesystemwatcher detectable.

for example. i wanna read and analyse log file parallel with using software.

So is it detectable?

TY.

Comment: Have you googled for filesystemwatcherwatcher ;)

Comment: Whose rules? The software license's? Your company's? Your government's? In any case, strongly consider if what you're doing is not only ethical, but if it's worth getting punished for, too.

Answer (score 2):

Is it detectable? Yes. It opens a connection to the remote server. See [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465.aspx).

Will it be detected? One way to tell is to use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and compare network traffic when using a `FileSystemWatcher` to network traffic when viewing the same directory in Windows Explorer. Windows Explorer also shows updates to the directory in real time, so very likely it's using the same API. But whether or not it's using the same API, it's still "watching" the directory.

So the question is, can someone monitoring network traffic tell the difference between using a `FileSystemWatcher` and viewing the folder in Windows Explorer? I'd say probably not.

But that's not the only way it could be "detected." It could be detected by an administrator or security software just checking to see what your PC is doing.

Comment: ReadDirectoryChangesW is monitoring only changes, as renaming, editing, deleting etc. Isn't it true?
Are you sure it is monitoring open with fsw?

Comment: No, I couldn't find the answer to that.